# Displaying two list of items with bootstrap 4 and Angular

Tags: css, angular

With Bootstrap 4, I want to display a list of item in the first three colums, then my card group in the next 9 columns.

Then when I make a selection of items it displays the results on the right part of the screen.

Here is the code sample :

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="categories">
      <li [ngClass]="currentCategorie==c?'active':''"(click)="getProductsByCategorie(c)" class="list-group-item clickable" *ngFor="let c of categories._embedded.categories">
        {{c.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for the card-group :

```
<div *ngIf="products">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let p of products._embedded.products">
      <div class="card">
        <img height="100" src="{{this.catService.host+'/photoProduct/'+p.id}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ p.name }}">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{p.name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{p.currentPrice | number: '0.2'}}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Any solutions ? Please

At the moment the display looks like :

```
Selector 1
Selector 2
Selector 3
Item 1 - Item 2 - Item 3 - Item 4
Item 5 - Item 6 ...
```

I want to have :

```
Selector 1 | Item 1 - Item 2 - Item 3
Selector 2 | Item 4 - Item 5 - Item 6
Selector 3 | Item 7 - Item 8 - Item 9
             Item 10 ...
             Item 13 ...
```

Comment: Bootstrap can have rows within rows. You want some a row with col-md4 and a col-md-8 and then in each of those create a row and loop through your lists with col-md-12 and col-md-4

Comment: thx it works : I create a row then 2 rows for data